# Why isn't pickle.dump() writing anything to the file?

Tags: python, pickle

About the `except` condition:
The code creates a file and I need pickle to dump a predefined dictionary (from an `import`ed file) into the file but after I run the code, the file is empty when I view it and no code runs after `pickle.dump()`.

I've tested that the dictionary is valid.
I've had similar code working before.

```py
from classes.py import *
import sys, os
try:
   import cPickle as pickle
except ModuleNotFoundError:
   import pickle

# Read player from file
def read(user):
    user_id = user.first_name + '_' +  str(user.id) + '.pkl'
    try:
        with open(os.path.join('C:/Users/jakee/Python/TelegramRPGBot/playerstats/', user_id), 'r+') as f:
            return pickle.load(f)
    # Creates file if it doesn't exist
    except FileNotFoundError:
        with open(os.path.join('C:/Users/jakee/Python/TelegramRPGBot/playerstats/', user_id), 'wb+') as f:
            pickle.dump(default_stats, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
            return default_stats
```

The dictionary in the second file is:

```py
default_stats = {
    'username': 0,
    'inventory': [[], []],
    'exp': 0,
    'current_exp': 0,
    'required_exp': 0,
    'level': 1,
    'max_stamina': 10,
    'class': '',
}
```

Comment: Did you actually define `default_stats` anywhere? If you did, you left it out; we need a complete [MCVE]. Also, side-note, the module name is `cPickle`, not `Cpickle`, so on Py2, you'll always be falling back to the non-accelerated module.

Comment: Are you calling `read(user)` somewhere? Nothing will get written (or read) unless you do.

Comment: Your code works for me in Python 3.7.3 (with definitions added for things you've left-out added). BTW, in Python 2.x the C version of the module is named `cPickle`, and in Python 3.x it's named `_pickle` — and because of it being misspelled in your code, it will never use it in Python 2 (although it will in Python 3 because it's done automatically).

Comment: Perhaps my code isn't working properly elsewhere I'll have to look into it, I am calling read(context) in my code with context from the telegram bot handler library (I'm working on an RPG bot for me and some friends but I'm fairly new to python and the library so it might have been too ambitious) and I've corrected the spelling of cPickle. Thanks for the help! I'll look into the problem again tomorrow

Comment: Just to specify I know that the file is being created with the correct name and everything it's just the contents of the file are empty and nothing happens after pickle.dump()

Comment: maybe creating `default_stats` before the `pickle.dump()` will help?

Comment: Oh I managed to get it working again, I have no idea what I changed but it's functional lol, is there a way to close the question?